# Create a custom JMS ConnectionFactory with ActiveMQ Artemis in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I am trying to run a Spring Boot app in local profile and looking to have an embedded broker in same JVM. I am setting up a Spring Boot 3 app with the below properties.

```
spring.artemis.mode=embedded
spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=true
```

I can see an instance of `CachedConnectionFactory` is getting injected by default by Spring. My app is dependent upon connection factories which I need to inject separately.

Main class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
import jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import jakarta.jms.JMSException;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfig {
    @Bean(name = "queueConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory getQueueConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://0");
        connectionFactory.createConnection();
        return connectionFactory;
    }
    
    //Comment above bean for connection factory and only keep this and the app will start up fine. 
    //@Bean
    public JmsTemplate initializeDefaultTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        System.out.println("default template created");
        return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

Below is the POM

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.art</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jakarta-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using the above code to create those connection custom factories but getting this error:

```
AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
```

I also tried `localhost`, `0.0.0.0`, and the machine's actual IP address for the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` URL. It didn't make a difference.

**Update/Workaround: not advised**

I used workaround of wrapper bean for each profile like this -

```java
@Component
public class JMSConnectionFactory {
  @Autowired // use constructor one
  private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
  // return the same connection factory
  public ConnectionFactory getXyzFactory(){
    return connectionFactory;
  }
  public ConnectionFactory getAbcFactory(){
    return connectionFactory;
  }
}
```

now, all other code parts where I am dependent on different connection factories(for non local environment, thats the case), I am injecting above component and getting the respective factory via those public methods.

Comment: Thanks for being quick. I tried localhost earlier. adding IP address didnt make difference.

Comment: yes, I am trying to run a spring boot app in local profile and looking to have embedded broker in same JVM. So yes, everything is under same JVM.

Comment: I had a proper activemq setup(including integration tests) I was using with spring 2.6. I am migrating to 3 and its breaking.

Comment: Just letting Spring Boot autoconfigure the embedded server should be all you need for you tests. The problem, imho, is that you are trying too much and work against the auto configuration.

Comment: for local environment, its giving me only 1 connection factory setup option, ion higher environment I using IBM MQ where I need to configure different factory based on different ssl requirement. to test the code in integration testing, I am not able to have different connection factories injected by qualified name. tried various combinations to work it out.

Comment: Why would you need multiple for your test, as you stated if you remove `@Configuration` it works. Which is because there is now only 1 `ConnectionFactory` that is being used. For the integration test you don't really need multiple (if you are using the embedded container that is).

Comment: My production code depends on multiple connection factories. To make integration test context look same like prod context, had to add extra wrapper.

Comment: No you don't you must need to make sure you are configuring the right things (and by simulating the configuration of prod doesn't without the same configuration and messaging infrastructure it really isn't an integration test).

Comment: might be right, any pointer what I am doing wrong? For now, my setup is same across local and prod with generic wrapper

Comment: Check the auto configuration of Spring how that creates the embedded connection it is more complex then your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simplify your properties to something like this:

```
spring.artemis.mode=embedded
spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=true
```

And then your code can look something like this:

```java
@Bean(name = "queueConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory getQueueConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://0");
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

Since the broker is embedded it doesn't expose a TCP acceptor.

Comment: thanks but its same - Failed to create session factory, caused by AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Added above, if you want direct project - its here -https://github.com/javatype/public/tree/main

Comment: Ultimately I ended up adding wrapper bean for factories and adding getter method instead of spring qualifier

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct to help other folks who have this same question in the future.

Comment: Its workaround more than a solution. I doubt its correct way.

Comment: A work-around is better than no solution at all. It may help someone else actually determine what the underlying problem is.

Comment: sorry for delay. added.

Comment: Those properties are useless as they are ignored due to the explicit registration of the `ConnectionFactory`.